# Get deployUrl from angular.json in component

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I know that it's possible to get `baseUrl` from angular.json using for example: `platformLocation.getBaseHrefFromDOM()`. **Is there any way to get `deployUrl` inside component in Angular 7?**

I am working on some speed improvements and I am storing my styling files using cdn, so it's stored at `deploy-url/styles.js`. I have to load this inside app.component.ts (lazy-loading styles) but I need full url for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what deployUrl is or where it is stored but if its inside a JSON file you can read the JSON file inside your environment.ts file and then access it via your environment but this might break AOT if you are using AOT so be careful.

Alternatively, just read the JSON file in the component that wants the data.

To read a JSON file:

```
import * as myJson from './path/my-file.json'
```

then:

```
console.log(myJson.deployUrl)
```

Comment: deployUrl is one of the variable from angular.json (config file). Based on that file angular app is build so it's rather bad idea to import variable in app from this file. I hope that there's another solution to get deployUrl inside builded app.